# Entity (or Document) with gedmo tree. Generate nice route

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, routes

i'm need create nice route as: http://www.site/rootCategory/childrenCategory/... for category page, and http://www.site/rootCategory/childrenCategory/.../productName for product page. I using symfony, doctrine (mongodb) and Gedmo bundle. I have Category and Product documents. As an option, I was thinking of making a controller that will give one or another page, and have route with slash... but this option is not good.. Have any idea?

Comment: Did you have a look at the symfony documentation about routing? http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html

Comment: Sure, but I do not know how I realize my problem

Comment: Then I'm afraid I don't know what you are asking for...

Comment: I'm create route to category page as `/category/{slug}`, but to children category I have acces by site/category/childrenSlug, and to parent i have site/category/parentSlug. I'm need create route wich generate route to parent category: site/category/parentSlug, and to children: site/category/parentSlug/childrenSlug